# algebraic function as solution of first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that a function that is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$ (rational polynomials with complex coefficients) is meromorphic. Is there any way to find out how that function would look like concretely if I know that it satisfies a differential equation?

The following equation came up:
$$ y' + y^2 + x^{-1}y +1 - x^{-2} = 0$$
and I want to show that it doesn't have a solution that is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$. The book I'm reading said that I can expand an algebraic solution around $\infty$, $0$ and $c \neq 0 $ to find out how it would look like and then prove by contradiction that such a solution doesn't exist. I'm thinking maybe it uses Puiseux series, but I'm not very familiar with that. Does anyone see how to solve this?

Comment: Using a degree argument, we can show $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $\deg p \neq \deg q$ cannot be a solution. But I don't know what to do in the $\deg p = \deg q$ case or the general algebraic function case.